# Automatically enter name/phone/email etc

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I may be searching for the wrong thing, which might explain why I can only find information on setting up password autofills.

I'm looking for the ability to for a user to enter email, phone, first + last names in an app, the same way some websites are able to do it, the options appearing above the keyboard.

I have the fields content type set in the storyboard (Name, Telephone Number, Email Address)

Can anyone advise if this is possible and how I go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password Autofill is the only feature that automatically does that on IOS Apps.

The other feature you are talking of "Contact Auto Fill" that you say happens on some websites on your mobile is a feature implemented in the Safari App.

If you go to your IOS settings and open Safari Settings, you'll see you can select a contact to use for contact and credit card autofill.
[Safari Settings Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwZCu.jpg) [Safari Settings Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PIMh.jpg)

To get such a feature, you would have to manually implement.

Automatic availability of such feature would probably have privacy concerns to user (meaning you can auto extract true user contact information by just making such a form in your app).